# Ruby OpenCV::CvCapture always returns the same frame

Tags: ruby, opencv

I have a problem, can you please help.

I am trying to read frames of my4 video file and show them in GUI::Window.

```
window = GUI::Window.new('Object Correspond')
cap = CvCapture.open('film.mp4')

10.times do
  frame = cap.query
  window.show_image frame
  sleep 1
end
```

I have tried with `cap.grab` and than `cap.retrieve` but it always returns only first frame.

Can you please tell me what am I doing wrong and how can I read frames and show them.

Thank you.

Comment: maybe the first 10 frames are identical in the video? :D

Comment: is there a cv::waitKey equivalent for ruby? maybe sleep doesnt give openCV the time to render the image. Please try `GUI::wait_key` instead of the `sleep 1`

Comment: I tryed with more than 10 frames and first 10 frames are not the same. There is a GUI::wait_key but it w8 for key I want to hold image for 1sec and it works if I load some images and display them, with video it does not work.

Comment: Did you try `GUI::wait_key` (and pressing key instead of waiting 1 sec) just to be sure that this is not the problem, please?

Comment: I have, but I think the problem is in a my .mp4 movie because I hove found some other movies that worked fine, and also .jpg pictures do not change if you put them on window, .png work.

Comment: maybe ffmpeg isnt linked correctly or completely to your openCV libs or something? jpeg should better work in any environment, I guess...

Comment: maybe, but i did some video conversions and it works now